# Group by Count of (Top 5) & Count of (All Other)

Tags: mysql, grouping, max

I have a query that I need to edit.  Currently, it returns 2 columns of data, a case label and the count (or total number of cases) handled during the previous 7 day period starting yesterday.  I need to change this output so that only 6 labels are in the output (i.e - always 6 rows of data).  These rows need to be the top 5 labels and the sum of the remaining labels as the 6th label (called "Other").  This is because this output is fed to a PHP script that presents the data on a web-based platform.

Finally, to illustrate here is a table of the output I need as well as the query below.

```
+-----------+---------------+  
| CaseLabel | CasesResolved |  
+-----------+---------------+  
| Label1    |            20 |  
| Label2    |            18 |
| Label3    |            10 |
| Label4    |             9 |
| Label5    |             7 |
| Other     |            12 |
+-----------+---------------+
```

Thanks in advance for any help! :-)

Running MySQL 5.096

### MySQL Code:

```
SELECT
    deskcases.Labels,
    COUNT(deskcases.Labels)AS CaseCount
FROM
    deskcases
WHERE
    deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE ''
AND deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%SPAM%'
AND deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%Online Orders%'
AND deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%Internal SPAM%'
AND deskcases.`Case Status` LIKE 'Resolved'
AND deskcases.`Resolved At` > CURDATE()- INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY
    deskcases.Labels
ORDER BY
    CaseCount DESC
```

Comment: just a comment, you don't need this line `AND deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%Internal SPAM%'` if you already have this `AND deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%SPAM%'`

Comment: @jcho360 good call! :)

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, probably the easiest way to express this is by using a temporary table:

```
create temporary table temp as (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    CaseLabel varchar(255),
    CasesResolved int
);

insert into temp(CaseLabel, CasesResolved)
    SELECT deskcases.Labels, COUNT(deskcases.Labels)AS CaseCount
    FROM deskcases
    WHERE deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE ''
          AND deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%SPAM%'
          AND deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%Online Orders%'
          AND deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%Internal SPAM%'
          AND deskcases.`Case Status` LIKE 'Resolved'
          AND deskcases.`Resolved At` > CURDATE()- INTERVAL 7 DAY
    GROUP BY deskcases.Labels
    ORDER BY CaseCount DESC;

select (case when id <= 5 then caselabel else 'Other' end),
       SUM(casesResolved) as CasesResolved
from temp
group by (case when id <= 5 then caselabel else 'Other' end)
order by MAX(id) desc
```

The `id` column in the temporary table adds a row number onto each row.  In any other real database, you would use the `row_number()` function, but MySQL does not support that.

Comment: Why a temp table? A subselect gets materialized in a temp table anyway (either in mem if small or on disk if big); Why the added complexity and the extra statements?

Comment: Hi Gordon, tried your query this morning and I'm getting a syntax error when I add in my select statement (added in all my code from my question above)  Any idea what could be causing? Or would it be too much trouble to edit the code you answered with to include my select statement?

Answer (score -1):

One possible option is to use a rank variable.

The dummy join will initialize the rank and the if will count up to 6.
All this stuff will first get resolved in the inner query, producing stuff like

```
| Label1    |            20 |  
| Label2    |            18 |
| Label3    |            10 |
| Label4    |             9 |
| Label5    |             7 |
| Label6    |            12 |
| Label7    |               |
| ......
```

The other query will then collapse this into the desired output.

```
select if(rank=6,"Other",sub.Labels) as Label, SUM(sub.CaseCount) from (
    SELECT
        if(@Rank < 6,@Rank:= @Rank + 1, @Rank) as Rank
        ,deskcases.Labels
        ,COUNT(deskcases.Labels) AS CaseCount
    FROM
        deskcases
    JOIN (@rank:= 0)
    WHERE
        deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE ''
    AND deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%SPAM%'
    AND deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%Online Orders%'
    AND deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%Internal SPAM%'
    AND deskcases.`Case Status` LIKE 'Resolved'
    AND deskcases.`Resolved At` > CURDATE()- INTERVAL 7 DAY
    GROUP BY
        deskcases.Labels
    ORDER BY
        CaseCount DESC
) sub
group by sub.rank ASC
```

Replacing the `labelx` into "Other" for the last line.

Comment: Johan,  Really like where you're heads at on this!  I just get a syntax error when I try to run it: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'deskcases.Labels,
        COUNT(deskcases.Labels) AS CaseCount
    FROM
        ' at line 4"

Comment: Missing `,`......... Oh and cool down I'm doing *you* a favor not the other way round.

Comment: Meant no offense, apologies.  I'm also getting another syntax error.  (Apologies again, I don't have any experience with queries this complex) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@rank:= 0)
    WHERE
        deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE ''
    AND deskcases.Labe' at line 8"

Comment: Think fixed that on the ipad now so cannot test the query.

Comment: OK. Please let me know if/when you get a chance to test/fix.  I'm probably not going to be able to figure this out. :-/

Comment: Hi Johan, did you get a chance to double check this?