# Syntax Error: Group Results by Top 5 & Other

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

So I don't know if I'm breaking any rules but I've been pretty frustrated with a question that was left previously unanswered post of mine:

[Group by Count of (Top 5) & Count of (All Other)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531942/group-by-count-of-top-5-count-of-all-other)

All I need is some help with fixing the following synatx error (from trying to run the code below, provided to me as a solution):

***"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@rank := 0)
    WHERE
        deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE ''
    AND deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE' at line 14"***

I've gotten no response from either person who originally provided solutions.  I'd imagine it would take 2 minutes to find the simple fix for someone as skilled as they are, but alas...radio silence ensued.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated! :)

Thank you!

```
    SELECT

IF(rank = 6, "Other", sub.Labels)AS Label,
 SUM(sub.CaseCount)AS ResolvedCases
FROM
    (
        SELECT

        IF(@Rank < 6 ,@Rank := @Rank + 1, @Rank)AS Rank,
        deskcases.Labels,
        COUNT(deskcases.Labels)AS CaseCount
    FROM
        deskcases,
        (SELECT @rank := 0)AS IgnoreAlias
    WHERE
        deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE ''
    AND deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%SPAM%'
    AND deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%Online Orders%'
    AND deskcases.`Case Status` LIKE 'Resolved'
    AND deskcases.`Created At` > CURDATE()- INTERVAL 30 DAY
    GROUP BY
        deskcases.Labels
    ORDER BY
        CaseCount DESC
    )sub
GROUP BY
    sub.rank ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never done a join like you have, but if you just comma separate the table it should work.  Also, any subqueries should be assigned an alias, even if never used...

```
from
   deskcases,
   ( select @rank := 0) as IgnoreAlias
where ...
```

Comment: DRapp, That makes two of us ;-). I made your edits and it worked! (well sort of) I actually only have 3 labels + 1 other (sum of rest) and I wanted to have 5 + other...but that must lie in somewhere in the rank logic?  Thank you greatly for your help so far.

Comment: @defaultuser909, you probably need IF( AT rank... instead of just IF( rank...  the AT indicates the variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to guess what you intended here, but you seem to be trying to JOIN to an expression, which isn't legal.

Check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html (or the equivalent for your version of MySQL) - you'll see you need to join to a table or table factor.

Comment: D Mac, Thanks for your reply but I'm still at at total loss. :-/ If you check out the link to my previous post, it should be more clear what I am trying to accomplish...

Comment: What happens when you just delete "JOIN (@rank := 0)"? I don't know why it is there, and maybe you don't need it.

Comment: Alternatively, try JOIN (select @ rank := 0) on 1 = 1, or something like that. This would make the JOIN valid and would initialize @ rank for you. Again, I don't understand what you're trying to do, so I could be quite wide of the mark.